# Is it possible to retrieve the start address from a pointer to allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory

It's known that you cannot in any standard way retrieve the allocated size of a memory block. For instance, if you do:

```
void *ptr = malloc(100);
```

There is no way to find out that it was 100 bytes allocated. But I started wondering if there is any way to do a similar thing, and that is retrieving the original pointer from a pointer pointing in that block. Like

```
void *ptr = malloc(100);
void *ptr2 = &ptr[10];
```

Can I in any way get `ptr` from `ptr2` without knowing that it points at element 10?

I have not found a good use case for it, but something that is at least reasonable (and a little crazy) is if you want a function to allocate a string and return a pointer to the first digit in that string. I'm mostly just curious if it is possible.

Comment: I know of no mechanism in the C language that provides for this.  If there were such mechanism, then getting the size of an allocated block of memory would be trivial by passing references to the end of the block instead of the beginning.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons No it would not be trivial, because then you need to know where the end is.

Comment: wrap your own malloc, and store start & size in a custom list. Then you can scan this list and see if the passed pointer is in a block

Comment: My point was that instead of passing around pointers to the start of a block, you would pass around pointers to the end of the block.

Comment: no it is not possible

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yes you could do that, but that's not the question.

Comment: if you want a function to allocate a string and return a pointer to the first digit in that string, return a structure. Or make 2 functions. One that returns the original pointer, and the other one that computes the pointer on the first digit. Basically XY problem

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, of course I would do something like that in a real situation. I was just curious about the inner details of C.

Comment: @Christian but still need to know the size

Comment: C isn't going to do anything special in modern systems, as malloc is a native call to the system. Some old systems (ex: AmigaOS) required to know the size to be able to free the pointer, in which case C lib had to store it when allocating, but not the case anymore

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting something, but if you have a pointer to the end, and you can get the original pointer (pointer to the beginning?) you can do simple arithmetic to get the size.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Provided the pointer points to the end. What if it points to for instance element 10 in an array of size 100, like in the code I posted.

Comment: @klutt `you need to know where the end is` Technically, if you could tell where the start of the allocated block is for any pointer, and you knew the start of the block, then you could just keep incrementing it and checking that the new pointer has the same start address. So what you are asking is a stronger proposition than just deriving the size of an allocated memory block. Neither is possible in a portable way, though.

Comment: @dxiv That is true, but it can technically be implemented in a say such that the operation to retrieve the original pointer invokes UB if you try to do it with a pointer that does not point to anything. And yes, this is just pure nerdiness.

Comment: I specified passing around pointers to the end in my supposition.  The point being that if we could derive the pointer to the original block, then taking up a paradigm of passing around pointers to the end (which are trivial to get at within the frame that the memory is allocated) would allow one to trivially calculate the size of the block without passing a second pointer or size argument to functions.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Ooooo, I missed that. Interesting abuse of features...

Comment: @klutt "it can technically be implemented in a say such that the operation to retrieve the original pointer invokes UB if you try to do it with a pointer that does not point to anything."  Detecting UB is not certainly doable, else the behavior being detected is not UB, but _defined behavior_.  Nice try though.

Comment: I can only wonder why people would *downvote* the question. Oh, the ever present thought police...

Comment: @dxiv Agree.  It  seems like C could use some magical math on the pointer to find the start (and could be easily done selectively in the old segment:offset DOS), but it is simply not portable as such encodings otherwise impose a restriction on how to do allocations.   And C is open many sorts of novel (and strange) implementations.

Comment: @dxiv I would not deny that it is not very "useful", but yeah I agree. It does not solve any problems, but questions like this can improve the understanding of how stuff works. And it's not a bad question.

Comment: @dxiv Personally, I love these nerdy questions where it's obvious it's not an XY-problem but just pure curiosity. It's actually all these strange quirks in C that made me so interested and learned so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrieve the start address from a pointer to allocated memory

No.  The details of allocation are an implementation detail, not specified by C.  No portable way to find the size nor start from an arbitrary offsetted pointer alone.

Comment: @pm100 The pointer in question is the arbitrary offsetted one such as `void *ptr2 = &ptr[10];`  Re-word for more clarity.